# Parse.Object.dirty returns false all the time (on Parse+Heroku)

Tags: heroku, parse-platform

I was using `user.dirty('family')` to detect if the `family` field is changed before on Parse. It works. After migrating to Parse+Heroku, it seems like this is always returning false. Is the usage correct?

I am using this in `Parse.User`'s `beforeSave`

Comment: Can you try logging the object's dirty keys to see if that helps? var dirtyKeys = user.dirtyKeys(); console.log(dirtyKeys). That may help debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found upgrading to v1.1 of https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-cloud-express fixes it